# what does `'CreateNote'`represent in this section?

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding

Referring to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis

I took this code section :

```
// CreateNote dialog
bot.dialog('CreateNote', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        // Resolve and store any Note.Title entity passed from LUIS.
        var intent = args.intent;
        var title = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Note.Title');

        var note = session.dialogData.note = {
          title: title ? title.entity : null,
        };
```

What i don't understand is what does `'CreateNote'`represent in this section?

And referring to this line :

```
var title = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Note.Title');
```

Assuming my intent name is `calendar.add` and my entity name `calendar.location`
will the intent.entities `calendar.add.calendar.location` create any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the internal identifier of the dialog, and can be referenced where necessary.

Regarding the second part, I don't think it will create confusion, but if you'll get back to this code two weeks later, you will scratch your head thinking why is it named that way, so it's more of a logistics kind of thing, in my opinion.

Comment: I edited my question can you answer the other half so i mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the official https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow . The 'CreateNote' is an identifier of your dialog and it can be used like this:

```
var inMemoryStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, 
function (session) {
    session.send("Welcome");
    session.beginDialog('perroDialog'); //Use beginDialog with the 
    //dialog identifier for starting perroDialog

}
).set('storage', inMemoryStorage); // Register in-memory storage 

//--------------------------DIALOGS WATERFALL------------------------
bot.dialog('perroDialog',
function (session) {
    session.send('You started perroDialog');
    session.endDialog(); //Back to / dialog (UniversalBot callback)
});
```